# After installing CentOS and rebooting, cannot see new boot entry

Tags: centos, rhel, powerpc, installer-anaconda

I am trying to install CentOS 7.3 bare-metal on a ppc64le machine. After completing the installation process using vncviewer, the last screen says the installation is completed and to reboot the system.

However when the system reboots, there are no boot entries for the disk that I installed CentOS on.

EDIT: This is also happened when installing RHEL 7.2, as they both use Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

I was installing CentOS on to a disk that already had a partition. The installer wanted to install a PReP partition which it couldn't as the first 4GB of the disk were full.

As I didn't need a PReP partition (because the machine has Petitboot) and I didn't want to rearrange my partitions, I pressed the "Do not install boot loader" as this was the only way (that I could find) that didn't require me to have a PReP partition to install CentOS.

[Turns out](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-disk-partitioning-setup-x86.html) that doing this means that the installer doesn't update the grub.cfg file. As Petitboot looks for this file and it isn't there, it doesn't display the new OS on the boot menu.

One fix is, after installation and before rebooting:

- go to the anaconda shell (press ctl+b then 2)
- run: `chroot /mnt/sysimage`
- update grub.cfg: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`